# Scala: Design pattern for object / renderer for UI

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

What would be a good design to have `renderer` and `object`.

I have made a few attempts but my code is really ugly right now.

Let's say I have a class `room` and a class which is supposed to handle rendering it.

- Who should call `renderer.render(room)` or should it even be that way ?
- Should I have `world.renderRoom()` ?
- Or should I have `room.renderWith(renderer)` ?

How can I build easy unit test, like `renderer.render(room, userInteraction)`

And what should the return be ?

`world.renderRoom().interact()....` ?

As you can tell, I have no idea what to do haha.

I have a few years of experience writing software but I am trying out `ScalaZ` and trying to be more `functional-programming`-like ; which is new to me.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering a screen is not a pure function as it has side effects. read up on the [IO monad](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/8ygjcq/can_someone_explain_to_me_the_benefits_of_io/).

You'd find that most (if not all) examples are around println and readln but the same principle applies.  In the context of scalaz take a look at [ZIO](https://scalaz.github.io/scalaz-zio/).

if as Tim suggests in the comment, render is a pure function then I suggest the render is a function of the model render(room) and room state is a fold of the actions `newRoomState=actions.foldLeft(oldRoomState)(state,action => someFunction(s,a))` (paint wall, add sofa whatever) see the [SAM pattern](http://sam.js.org). And world which accepts renders (flatMaps/reduce over several renders?!) is the part that warrants an IO monad)

Comment: Rendering a screen **is** functional: You create a function that takes your object and returns a screen, e.g. as a PNG image. It is the **display** side that is non-functional, and that is not what the question is about.

Comment: what I understood is that the renderer updates the display (world.renderRoom ~ System.println)

Comment: Thanks, I made great progress on my project using ZIO

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be asking about a number of different things, which makes it difficult to answer except in very general ways.

Don't add rendering code to data objects because that breaks separation of concerns. The classic OO example of a `Shape` class with a `draw` method is great for teaching, but it joins the data about the shape (e.g. number of sides) with a specific way of drawing it. Instead, create a function `render(s: Shape)` that uses the data in the `Shape` to draw in the particular way you want (2D, 3D filled, list of coordinates etc.).

Make your `render` code functional so that it returns the rendered data rather than calling a rendering library as a side effect. The rendering library will need to be functional and return rendered results rather than drawing directly to the screen.

Pass the rendering library to the `render` function (as an `implicit` parameter) rather than using a global object. This allows you to test the rendering with a mock renderer, and is a more flexible design anyway. But you may still need different `render` functions for different output devices or styles.

Separate rendering from composition of rendered components so that you can test them independently.

Build the whole image in a functional way and then have a single non-functional operation to display the new image (by replacing the current image).

Use the user interaction to create a modified scene with an updated `room` and then re-render the whole scene.

**TL;DR**

```
val room = Room(width, length, height)
val room3D = render(room, render3D)
val house = compose(room3d, ..., compose3D)

screen.display(house)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it helped me understand what I had to do !